# c# net 6.0 winform application using httpclient with proxy disposed but socket exhaustion

Tags: c#

[image]

here's some picture of netstat-n of windows 10
ALL Socket is TIME_WAIT
even HttpClient disposed

my proxy endpoint is same and
each proxy has same ip endpoint but different credentials

exceed over almost 900~1000 httpclient instance created
suddenly all stopped and timeout exception happened
here's my code

```
using (HttpClient client = InitClient(proxy,cookie))
{
}
```

here's InitClient code

```
 var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
                CookieContainer = (cookie == null) ? new CookieContainer() : cookie,
                PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; },
                },
                UseProxy = true,
                Proxy = proxy

            };

            HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(handler, true);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
            _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);
```

how can i dispose socket with handler or httpclient disposed ?

its not asp.net its winform program

Comment: *DON'T* dispose HttpClient, reuse it. You're *causing* the exhaustion by disposing the client. HttpClient is thread-safe and meant to be reused. This is mentioned in all guides and almost all of them link to [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your system](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: The [HttpClient Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines) explicitly say that you should either use a singleton instance with restricted pool lifetime or use HttpClientFactory

Comment: its not a asp.net web it .net form application 
and its safe with reuse different cookie and different ip(proxy) ?